# Glass Error opening Experience Editor (ObjectToSwitchTo)

Tags: glass-mapper

I'm using `@Html.Glass().Editable(Model, x => x.MyProperty)` for some of our single-text / rich text fields. When I load the site with this code in the view everything looks fine. However, when I open the Experience Editor I see this error:

`Value cannot be null. Parameter name: objectToSwitchTo.`

```
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Common.Switcher`2.Enter(TValue objectToSwitchTo)
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.GlassHtml.MakeEditable[T](Expression`1 field, Expression`1 standardOutput, T model, Object parameters, Context context, Database database, TextWriter writer)
```

I've seen a few other SO threads about this but no real solutions for me. I'm using a data source set on the rendering. I've stepped through the entire process and don't see any null attributes in my model after using `GetDataSourceItem<MyClass>`. However, one thing I noticed is that my Sitecore ID field is all zeroes. I saw a different error prior to this, saying I needed to add a Sitecore ID field to my model, so I did. My code for the ID field is as follows:

```
    [SitecoreId]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; }
```

My Glass version is `4.5.0.4` which I believe is still pretty recent.

Comment: If I change my definition of the `Id` field to `{ get; set; }`, it works...

Comment: You need a setter for the Id field so Glass can map your model back to Sitecore Item. From what I remember, the setter doesn't have to be public. `[SitecoreId] public virtual Guid Id { get; private set; }` should do the trick.

Comment: It's funny because I tried `private set` first and it still didn't work. Regardless, it seems like I've found a solution to the problem - using `{ get; set; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact I was getting an empty ID made me think that maybe Glass wasn't able to set the item ID on the property, so I changed my field definition from:

```
[SitecoreId]
public virtual Guid Id { get; }
```

to:

```
[SitecoreId]
public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
```

Now things are working fine.